# prompt.sync module requiring ()

Tags: javascript, package, node-modules, prompt

Below is a simple programme importing few modules in Node.js

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
const http = require('http');
const file = require('fs')
const low = require('lodash');
```

In all the module importing , we just put the name of module inside the brackets. However , why in case of `prompt-sync` we need to put an extra pair of function.
It should be also like `const prompt =require('prompt-sync')` . Why is it not so ?

Answer (score 0):

the first line of code can be broken down into three steps:

1. require('prompt-sync') (what has been imported should be a function,let's call it 'funtion A')
2. execute the 'funtion A' we've just imported at the first step, and then we get a result (just call it 'result A')
3. let the variable'prompt' get the value of 'result A'

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with an example like what you are saying. Actually am a newbie in node and programming so unable to follow it. Seeing an example would help me a lot.